# How to know User ranking on Stack Overflow by country

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, rankings, user-rank

Is it possible to view a report of the all-time user ranking by country, or if there any other workarounds to find this information?

Comment: I honestly don't know how pertinent that information would be. The "location" field in user profiles is optional and not restricted to countries.

Comment: Would this be by ip or by whats in your profile? I ask because by ip would expose information that people may not want exposed

Comment: There is a statistic somewhere that is similar. I think it had to do with the german careers launch, but not sure.

Comment: I doubt that this info ever will be made available. Either [CommonsWare](http://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) will be the only user in the country of "Over Here!", or his true location is going to be revealed, which is perhaps not what he or anyone else would want.

Comment: [data.se] is your best bet I think.

Comment: I'm thinking more in the registration country rather than the user IP I wasn't aware of SS Data Explorer, I'll check into it! thanks!

Comment: ✋ **Top users from All Countries around World: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1250968/**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a Data Explorer query that might help:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/126577/top-users-by-location

As BoltClock points out, it's by no means foolproof.

Tip: if you're looking for a particular city with a non-unique name, entering something like e.g. `santiago%chile` in the location field may be helpful.

Comment: Are people still forking from my original query? Aw shucks :3 I should note that all it really does is a case-insensitive `LIKE` match on the Location field, which isn't completely accurate if you're worried about things like abbreviations, misspellings and fake particulars.